# Capture, modify and then output audio in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, audio, electron

I'm trying to capture, modify and finally output audio in node with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) (Mac OSX). These are the steps:

1. Capture the audio before it's output, possibly via CoreAudio.
2. Modify the audio stream/buffer via the Web Audio API.
3. Output the modified buffer to the sound device.

I've tried [node-core-audio](https://github.com/ZECTBynmo/node-core-audio). However, the most I can achieve is a rapid glitching sound. Other than this a I haven't been able to find a good solution I/O of audio.

How can I achieve this without sacrificing sound quality?

Comment: Did you find anything interesting @Luke?

Comment: @ZogStriP No, unfortunately there didn't seem to be a solution at the time - which is a shame.

Comment: Have you looked into [WebRTC](https://github.com/webrtc/samples)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, but on MacOS, this is not yet possible. I came accross the problem of recording system sound on MacOS, and I found a solution. Finally! Using Soundflower and Javascript with electron, I finally could record system audio. Though it is not exactly what you want, I modified this audio stream by adding it with video stream from the System, then displayed it to the user. [Here is my solution to the issue IN this detailed blog post](https://doumer.me/record-system-sound-on-macos-with-javascript-and-soundflower/) I think it is better than posting all the long steps here on stackoverflow.

Comment: In our project we need: Scenario: Suppose I am talking with someone over an application like skype or zoom. I want our Electron application to capture what I hear via my speaker and send it to a transcribing service. We need that for Windows and MacOS. We are not bothered about MacOS at the moment. 

What do you think are our options. Thank you

Comment: WebRTC does that well, you can use the js api and select the appropriate sound output device

Comment: @JohnCode Could you elaborate on that? I tried today via the GetUserMediaDevice, setting the device is to an output device, but am only able to stream input devices.